# How to change the default size of objects in Oracle BPA

Tags: diagram, notation, bpmn, diagramming

i have a question regarding the size of objects that are used in EPC notation in Oracle Business Process Architect. Is there any possible way to change the default size of functions and events instead of changing the size of each object separately? 
Thanks in advance!